# Is the time cost of creating objects in Python relevant for performance analysis?

Tags: python

Let me present a scenario. I have to write a module for validating Python dictionaries. Each key in the dictionary stores 2 things: a value, and type. Something like this:

```
d = {
    'key1': {
        'type' : 'string',
        'value' : 'The quick brown fox'
    },
    'key2': {
        'type' : 'integer',
        'value' : 23
    }
}
```

Now the value must be validated depending on its type. In other words, values of the same type will have the same validation. There is also a significant amount of validation that is common to all types of values.

The first thing that came to my mind was to write a validation class for every type of data present, and each of these classes will inherit from a base class which will contain the common validations. I have around 17 types of data, so that would mean if all data types are present in the dictionary, I would need to create 17 different Python objects to validate the one dictionary.

So now my question is this: is the time cost of creating objects relevant in this case? Or should I just try to do the entire thing using one giant method?

Comment: you got tuples as keys? and want to validate part of the key by the type also stored in the key? did you try to measure instantiating 17 objects? what are your timing contraints? _Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%._

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry, my wording was a bit confusing. I edited the question with more details.

Comment: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth (quote modified - due to being too long ;) )

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth, Computer Programming as an Art (1974) p.671

Comment: @handras  .. unless it is one of thos 3% that mostly not get quoted :)

Comment: Then the question will be something like: "Instantiating is too slow, here is the result of my measurements. How it can be done faster." I have a gut feeling that instantiating won't be a bottleneck. Please [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html).

Comment: Impossible to answer currently. I don't follow the "17 objects" being created, but if it's only done once, it probably doesn't matter

Comment: In case you haven't come across it yet, there is a library [fastjsonschema](https://horejsek.github.io/python-fastjsonschema/) that does the type of dictionary validation that you are looking for and it is specifically designed with speed in mind.